# EEEK I have temporary powers to view flag count

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface, vote-to-close

As a 3K user with close privileges on MSO, if I accidentally flag a question as "It doesn't belong here or is duplicate", my flag is supposed to be automatically converted to a close vote.

However after the new close reasons were rolled out, there is an odd UI behavior that is initially showing it as a flag, and at the same time is showing me the flag count on the post.

### After Flagging

[image]

### After Refreshing Page

Once I refresh the page, all is well, and my flag is moved over to where it belongs and I can't see the number of flags anymore.

[image]

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a crap question that needs closed
2. Flag with "It doesn't belong here or is duplicate"
3. Select appropriate reason*
4. Enjoy seeing how many flags the question has.
5. Refresh the page
6. See the flag count disappear and your close vote displayed in the correct place.

As pointed out in the comments by Matt (and the current duplicate), the value next to "flag" might not be the flag count, but actually the correct close vote count in the wrong place.  Refreshing still corrects the UI bug regardless of what is actually displayed.

<sup>* - Since I've only figured out the reproduction steps this morning, I have only experimented with "Primarily Opinion based" and "Off-topic/Not a programming question".  I suspect all of the close reasons will behave the same and I don't want to randomly cast close votes to test unless the question deserves it.</sup>

(This has only been tested on MSO since it is the only site I have VTC privileges, but I would assume it behaves the same on all sites that have the new close system in place).

Comment: This is on mobile? Because that's where I've seen similar behaviour before.

Comment: No, the full site.  Haven't checked if it is the same behavior on mobile.

Comment: The real bug here is that you can flag for closure when you have enough reputation to vote to close

Comment: @JanDvorak that's not really a bug.  As I mentioned in my first sentence, the system already takes care of that and automatically converts my flag into a close vote.  The UI is just not showing that initially.

Comment: @Matt sure looks to be a duplicate.  I have voted to close as such.

Comment: @psubsee2003 As this seems to be the much better worded version of the two perhaps a reverse duplicate (i.e. the older question be marked as a duplicate of the newer)

Comment: it could be new type of  privilege to view flag weight to 17.5k user

Comment: @psubsee2003: I've stolen your image for the duplicate as its clearer than the original ;).